# Weird String returned from LastBootUpTime

Tags: c#, datetime, wmi

I'm returning a value from `Win32_OperatingSystem` using `System.Management` (I know about `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` but I'm just doing some testing).

This is what I run:

```
string bootTime = "";
//Creating a management searcher object
ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtObjSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
//Collection to hold "results"
ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = mgmtObjSearcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mgmtObject in objCollection)
{
    bootTime = mgmtObject["LastBootUpTime"].ToString();
}
```

But when trying to run `Convert.ToDateTime(bootTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");` I get the following error:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

It looks like the LastBootUpTime value is being returned as `20190703085750.500000+060` which I can't seem to convert using `Convert.ToDateTime` and can't work with using `DateTime.Parse`

Can someone lend a helping hand and let me know where I'm going wrong? I just want to return the LastBootUpTime and convert a specific string format ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"). Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: It is not an ordinary DateTime value. You need to use the  WMI `System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter` to convert it as explained in the docs

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Management_ManagementDateTimeConverter_ToDateTime_System_String_

Comment: Thank you both, this is now working :)

Comment: @I.TDelinquent - Be careful about case sensitivity in your ToString argument. `hh` is for a 12-hour clock, and is meaningless without also including `t` or `tt` to get AM/PM. You probably mean to use `HH` for a 24-hour clock.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thank you for the warning :) I don't think it matters too much since I'm just comparing it again the current time in the same format and getting the total amount of days. Am I being naive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp's and Soner Gönül's comments, this is what I ended up with:

```
string bootTime = "";
//Creating a management searcher object
ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtObjSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
//Collection to hold "results"
ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = mgmtObjSearcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mgmtObject in objCollection)
{
    bootTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mgmtObject["LastBootUpTime"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

**UPDATE**
Following infinit_e comment, this is how I would get the value without using a `foreach` loop:

```
string bootTime = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get()
    .OfType<ManagementObject>()
    .First()
    .Properties["LastBootUpTime"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I realize this is a few months old, but could you share how to do without the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @infinit_e I have updated my answer following your comment :)

Comment: Just a note about the style of the second code snipped. Either use `First` or handle nulls properly. Using `FirstOrDefault` and assuming it will allways return something is not how its meant to be used.

Comment: @CSharpie I have changed the snippet to use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. Thank you for this :)

Comment: Thank you for the update @I.TDelinquent! I would not have expected I would needed to combine so many methods. Far more complicated than the PowerShell code I'm used to using.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent thank you for helping me figure this out. I took your example and figured out how to get it into a more normal date format.
`System.DateTime bootTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(searcher.Get()            .OfType<ManagementObject>().First().Properties["LastBootUpTime"].Value.ToString());`